# how to do load testing using jmeter on site hosted by amazon cloud.Is it affect the billing or something else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, aws-sdk, jmeter-plugins

If I want to test the website which is hosted by amazon cloud,then what are the steps which are required and what about from billing perspective.What are the charges?Is it increased by hours or depends upon virtual users which i am entering or how will database fetch the users??Basically what is the procedure as  i am doing for the first time.Please tell from scratch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you edit the question and make it clear that you will use jmeter for load testing instead of just adding the tag. Also, add the tag aws, and other related tags based on the service you are using.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know which Amazon Service is use to host the application. There are different services and different packages. No one can really give an objective answer without knowing the service/package that is being used.

For most of products, billing is by hours, BUT that should not concern you while testing through JMeter. Similarly, no. of virtual users is also not a main factor to worry about. Factors that you should know before load-testing such application are:

- You should be load-testing an application only with proper permission from owners as otherwise it could be considered DDOS attack
- You should know the Amazon service name that is actually used to host it. And you should know if there are any processing/bandwidth limitations etc

To read more about Aamazon services visit following links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services#List_of_products
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad and doesn't contain enough details to provide anticipated charges. I suggest referring the following material:

- [Amazon EC2 Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) - exhaustive information on associated costs of instances, bandwidth, etc.
- [jmeter-ec2](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) - script which makes the process of deploying JMeter to Amazon EC2 instances much easier.
- If your application is scalable and uses [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) - [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) will be extremely useful